# How to get ASP.NET Bundle to refresh whenever files are changed?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

Is it possible to configure ASP.NET Bundles to auto-rebuild whenever a script file changes? Currently I need to stop and restart my solution before the bundles recompile and changes take effect.

My bundle config looks as follows (using BabelBundle to transpile JSX):

```
bundles.Add(new BabelBundle("~/bundles/main").Include(
            "~/Scripts/subFolder/*.jsx",
            "~/Scripts/helloWorld.jsx"
            ));
```

And I reference it in my layout page as follows:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/bundles/main")"></script>
```

Debug is set to "true" in web.config, if that matters:

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to do this, so I ditched ASP.NET Bundles, and I used webpack instead. Easy to set up and works like a charm.